# PHP after Delete recording with foreign key, check int the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
Product : 

 - id : int;
 - name : varchar(255);
 - content : varchar(255);
 - categories_id : int (foreign key)

Categories : 

 - id : int;
 - title : varchar(255);
```

when I want to delete a product, I want to check is that the category is already exist.
I do not want to delete a category already used in the product table

```
     $sql = $db->query("SELECT p.*, c.* FROM product as c INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id  = p.categories_id   ");
        $res = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $p = $res['id'];

        $m_id = $_POST['id '];
                        $sql = $db->query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = $m_id AND categories_id =  '$c' )");
    if($sql){echo 'success';

                                    }else{
   echo 'Impossible to delete this categories becauss already exist in the table product, must be removed product  in the table prodcut, ';
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Alok; when I want to delete a product, I want to check is that the category is already exist. I do not want to delete a category already used in the product table

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete category and before deleting it you want to check if category is being used in any product?

Comment: @Talha Malik, yes that's my problem

Comment: you can also define the relation between two tables and restrict the deletion if it exists in the product table. but your table must have INNODB storage engine to define the relation between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to be sure, that a parent row will not being deleted when it is referenced.

**Enforce the constraint using foreign keys**

You can define a foreign key constraint on the tables with the `ON DELETE NO ACTION` option to prevent such action on the parent table.

This is the most reliable option, but it has some prerequirements in MySQL, such as:

- `InnoDB` storage engine (both tables)
- There must be at least a `UNIQUE` constraint on the referenced column in the parent table

MySQL will report an error when you'll try to delete a row from the categories table and there is a referencing record in the products table.

**You can check in the delete query if there is a child row**

```
DELETE FROM
  categories
WHERE
  id = :id -- < Parameter
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.categories_id = categories.id)
```

This will succeed in any cases, but won't delete the record when there is a referencing record.
You can check the rows affected right after the query, or you can issue a SELECT to check if the category is still there.

The delete in this form is transaction safe and handles race conditions properly.

**SELECT and DELETE from code**

You can check if there is a record in the child table and issue a delete when this condition is false, however THIS IS NOT TRANSACTION SAFE, NOR HANDLES RACE CONDITION on it's own.

You either have to start a transaction manually and commit/rollback it, or you can use the `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` syntax to lock the records, but this won't stop other threads to INSERT into the products table.

**Summary**

Define the foreign key constraint in the database, this is the most reliable solution to prevent accidental deletion and to enforce data integrity.

Read more about the foreign key options in the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

You can read about locking reads (`SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`) on the following manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: is that I can display a success message when the category not exist
and an error message when the class exist ?

Comment: What do you mean, with which method? Is it matter if you are deleting a non-eixsting record? Is it an error if you try it? Should you report an error after executing the query or is it fine before it? Can you even reach the delete function (without 'hacking') when there is no such record?

Answer (score 0):

There many problems with your current code:
1. You don't need every column value when you perform SELECT query.
2. `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` this will return multiple rows not single id.
3. You haven't added WHERE clause in first query for product ID.
4. In `DELETE` query you don't need to specify category ID.

So you can update your code as follow.

```
<?php
$m_id = $_POST['id '];
$sql = $db->query("SELECT c.id FROM categories as c INNER JOIN product as p ON c.id  = p.categories_id WHERE p.id=".$m_id."");
$res = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(sizeof($res)>0) { // Making sure there is no category match in categories table. 
    echo 'Impossible to delete this product, must be removed categories in the table categories';
} else { // No matching row found in categories table, remove product safely. 
     $sql = $db->query("DELETE FROM product WHERE id = $m_id");
     if ($sql) {
         echo 'success';
    }
}
```

> I've edited your question to meet your requirements. General practice is to use **foreign key constraints** and upon delete MySQL automatically throws exception if parent row exists in reference table. 
> Complete manual on foreign keys:
>  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Your highlighted part about foreign keys is not complete. MySQL will report an error on delete when the foreign key is present **AND** it is defined with the `ON DELETE NO ACTION` option. There are more actions available for the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` clauses, including `CASCADE` which will delete all child rows on delete. Be precise, because this kind of misunderstanding can lead to serious data losses.

Comment: @Pred I've already mentioned in my answer that it will throw exception on using foreign keys. And if it's a exception there must be something wrong. It won't let you delete the row, and if it's not going to let you delete the row then there is no "data loses". Though added reference to the complete manual of the foreign keys.

Comment: Read the doc you've linked, it can allow deletes. Read my comment too.

Comment: I would start reading with this part: **CASCADE:** Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

Comment: If the person don't know about a concept TOTALLY then he/she should go through the entire document without jumping to a specific danger section!

Comment: If they do (what I doubt), that part is still misleading. Your comment changes nothing.

Comment: I don't know if a good "learner" does that, if you still want more details to be added in my answer your edits are more then welcome.

Comment: A good learner won't ask here a question like this, since there are shitload of articles to read on the net in this topic. Stop this here, since this discussion (how the reader acts) is off-topic here. You've tried to mask your mistake/lack of knowledge/will to improve your answer with the imagined behaviour of the askers here. My point is still valid, your answer is missing important information.

Comment: A good learner always asks the question here, more then 100K reputation users ask the question here. As it's going off topic I don't want to argue more, the user who has asked the question wasn't interested in foreign key concepts. I've added it for future readers with reference link so that they go trough it when-ever they find kind of problem. My answer has enough information to convey to a learner! Don't except to write FULL MANUAL/(Copy rather) in answer.